# Connect two entities from different LANs without extra configuration

Tags: networking, tcp, network-programming, client-server

This may seem a naive question, since the computer networks knowledge from university days has almost vanished throughout the years, but before getting my hands on a book relevant on this topic, I would like to find out what more experienced folks out there know about this.

Basically I would like to be able to connect a client (C) to a remote server (S), sitting in separate LANs, without adding special rules (e.g. port forwarding) to any of the routers in between.

I know that some applications (TeamViewer) use broker servers for connecting a client to a remote machine, but what I don't know is if the whole traffic between them goes through the broker server.

For my use case, I would use such a server only for initial discovery of the peers (more exactly the discovery of S by C), then the traffic would go through a connection directly initiated by C towards S.

Would such an approach be possible?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately if the devices reside in networks separated by the Internet your first hurdle concerns RFC1918. In order to connect to a private IP you will have to use some level of NAT. To over come this is to build a VPN connection between the two networks affectively connecting as if each are local to the other. Please note that to avoid any NAT configuration in this scenario requires that the private networks are using different subnets IPs

Comment: I gave it more thought after asking this and realized that it cannot be possible to access a computer in a private network just by knowing the network's external IP address and port. It doesn't really make sense, since the router that interfaces the network has to have a rule to know where to forward the packets. So as you said, it's either VPN or a NAT rule. In my case, I think I am forced to stick to the second one. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: After looking more into this, I ended up using zeroconf which is exactly what I needed in the first place.